# ¿Por qué Google Chrome regresa la alerta de "Tu contraseña quedo expuesta debido a una violacion de la seguridad de los datos"?

Tags: php, html, html5, google-chrome

Desde la última versión de Google Chrome (Versión 84.0), he tenido este problema. El navegador muestra una alerta de seguridad después de haber iniciado sesión en un formulario HTML (que usa de paso PHP). Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué pasa esto y cómo solucionarlo?

La alerta de Google Chrome después de haber hecho submit al formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código HTML

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.mipaginaweb.com.mx/demoapp/login/get-login">
    <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
    <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required=""></div>
    <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Mi página web trabaja con un certificado ssl vigente y válido. Estaría agradecido si de paso pudieran decirme a qué se debe esta alerta de seguridad y cómo poder solucionarlo para que deje de salir esta molesta alerta que sale en todas partes de mi sitio web.

Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome ha implementado una alerta de seguridad donde te avisa cuando la combinacion usuario/password que usas aparece en listas conocidas de contraseñas filtradas/robadas.

Si solo es un usuario de prueba como 'admin' y clave '123' no deberias preocuparte, pero si es tu usuario y contraseña que se supone solo sabes tu, deberias preocuparte de revisar en que sitios usas dicha combinacion usuario/contraseña y cambiarla cuanto antes.

Si solo estas testeando un sitio con un usuario/password de prueba usa una combinacion menos comun para evitar dicho mensaje.

Articulo sobre como funciona esta caracteristica: https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html

Revisa las respuestas a este problema en https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23534509?hl=en